# Some questions about thread synchronization

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm having some questions I'd like to clarify.

1. Volatile read ensure you read the
   latest value of a variable. Does it
   means that it forces to all CPU's to
   flush their cached values for that
   variable? only that variable or all?
   So if it will force all CPUs to
   flush cached writes and get latest
   version from main memory, is this a
   memory barrier?
2. Volatile write ensure you write a
   value to the variable in main
   memory. Does it means that it void
   all the cached values for that
   variable in all CPUs?
3. Are you using a memory barrier when
   you use the keyword volatile?
4. Interloked performs a
   read/modify/write in an atomic
   operation. Does Interlocked ensure
   that you are for example
   incrementing the latest version of a
   variable and the other CPUs will see
   this change? I think so because it's
   supposed to use a memory barrier,
   but I'm not sure. So could we say
   that Interloked is doing a
   VolatileRead/modify/VolatileWrite
   atomically?
5. When you use a memory barrier, does
   it affect to all variables in all
   CPUS, or just the surrounding ones?
6. Locking is expensive because it
   causes two memory barriers and a
   "context switch" if the thread has
   to wait, but then what is the
   advantage of Interlocked? just to
   avoid the "context switch"?
7. What is the deal with
   ReaderWriterLockSlim and
   recursivity? I didn't understans
   what is the issue.

As you can see, I have a total mess in my mind right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are great questions, but they should be asked as separate posts. I suggest deleting this post and breaking it up into several smaller posts.

Comment: I guess I should elaborate as to why: 1. Long posts discourage readers to finish (so you eliminate potential answerers). 2. Someone migrate know the answe to one of these questions but not all and feel they shouldn't post an incomplete answer (so you eliminate more answerers). 3. Long questions with many questions take a lot of time to respond to (so you discourage even more answerers). You'll get better and more responses if you break this post up.

Comment: Sorry for the typos in the above; replace "migrate know the answe" to "might know the answer."

Comment: Yes, you have a point there. I was about to do it but as Brian replied in that gently way... I'll leave it. I'll remember your advice for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before answering your questions I should point out that memory barriers affect more than just the CPU. There are really two memory models in play when an application runs. One is at the hardware level and the other is at the software level. As a developer you have to code for the weakest combination of the different elements from both. With the CLR and an x86 architecture this usually means the CLR is more important because the x86 architecture actually has a fairly strong memory model. In other words, the `volatile` keyword and other memory barriers mechanisms will affect how the JIT produces code as well.

> 1.Volatile read ensure you read the latest value of a variable. Does it
>   means that it forces to all CPU's to
>   flush their cached values for that
>   variable? only that variable or all?
>   So if it will force all CPUs to flush
>   cached writes and get latest version
>   from main memory, is this a memory
>   barrier?

First, technically a volatile read does not ensure you read the latest value of a variable. All it actually means is that no other read or write can occur before the volatile one. However, the effect is that the read has to come from main memory *if* it is preceded by another volatile read. Second, no, a volatile read has no influence on other writes so it does not force all CPUs to flush their write cache. Third, yes a volatile operation is considered a memory barrier.

> 2.Volatile write ensure you write a value to the variable in main memory.
>   Does it means that it void all the
>   cached values for that variable in all
>   CPUs?

Similiar to a volatile read, a volatile write is technically about ordering. It ensures that no other read or write can occur after the volatile one. It does not mean that the write in question immediately gets committed. It only affects the CPU executing that thread. Interestingly, the x86 architecture actually treats *all* writes as volatile. But, the CLR does not (at least the ECMA specification). That is why you still have to use a volatile operation on writes. This is one example of coding for the weakest memory model element from both the hardware and software level.

> 3.Are you using a memory barrier when you use the keyword volatile?

Yes. There are two types of memory barriers. Full fences and half fences. Half fences can either guarentee acquire semantics (volatile read) or release semantics (volatile write), but not both at the same time. A full fence (via `Thread.MemoryBarrier` for example) guarentees both.

> 4.Interloked performs a read/modify/write in an atomic
>   operation. Does Interlocked ensure
>   that you are for example incrementing
>   the latest version of a variable and
>   the other CPUs will see this change? I
>   think so because it's supposed to use
>   a memory barrier, but I'm not sure. So
>   could we say that Interloked is doing
>   a VolatileRead/modify/VolatileWrite
>   atomically?

Yep. And for what is worth the interlocked increment and decrement operations can be implemented with a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operation. In .NET you would use the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method in a loop until the operation succeeded. I bet the `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement` methods use a native CPU instruction though, but I am prepared to be wrong about that.

> 5.When you use a memory barrier, does it affect to all variables in all
>   CPUS, or just the surrounding ones?

It will affect all memory accesses, but only on the CPU executing that thread.

> 6.Locking is expensive because it causes two memory barriers and a
>   "context switch" if the thread has to
>   wait, but then what is the advantage
>   of Interlocked? just to avoid the
>   "context switch"?

Yeah basically. The thread never blocks with interlocked operations.

> 7.What is the deal with ReaderWriterLockSlim and recursivity?
>   I didn't understans what is the issue.

You cannot acquire the lock twice on the same thread without first releasing it. There is more information on [Joe Duffy's blog](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,c4ea3d6d-190a-48f8-a677-44a438d8386b.aspx).

Comment: What a shame I can just up vote you just once. What I don't understand is why a memory barrier only affects to one CPU, what does happen with the others? I mean, if CPU1 has a copy of a variable in its cache, and I write that variable with a memory barrier from CPU2, are you implying that CPU1 won't see the change unless it does a memory barrier too?  And thanks again, I owe you a pint.

Comment: @bitbitbit: That is exactly what I am saying! That is why lock-free coding strategies are incredibly difficult to get right.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with locks is that any thread that acquires a lock must assume the risk that other threads may hold the lock for an arbitrary length of time.  A Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange call is guaranteed to return almost instantly (whether it succeeds or not); except under conditions of deliberately-heavy contention, a *short* CompareExchange spinlock will also return quickly.  If a thread acquires a lock and then goes off and does other things before it releases it, other threads will have to wait for those other things to finish before they can acquire the lock.  No such danger exists with a CompareExchange spinlock.  Unless other threads are actively hitting spinlock themselves, the spinlock will complete quickly.